# Adding header to HttpGet request

Tags: java, android, get, http-headers

I am attempting to return a json get API call that requires a header to be set with each request, I have attempted to attach the addHeader() parameter to my request but this seems to not work and return a 400 error each time, am I missing any additional parameters or should be using something else? any help will go a long way thanks!

```
    public String getJSON(String address, String header) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(address);

    if(header != null){

        httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + header);

    }

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {

            errorCode = statusCode;

        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }


    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: by enabling apache http client debug log you see what is going in header part. And when I look at your code it seems totally fine. Btw http 400 is bad request error it can also be because of your http url or parameter.

Comment: You were right, I made an error in one of the GET parameters, it was the last place I thought to look! thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem anything wrong with your usage of the addHeader() method, I would try debugging and analysing the request to check that the header and address you are using are correct.

A HTTP 400 indicates that the request is malformed, if I had to guess I'd say that the address/header you are using are being set but are not what the web server is expecting.

Comment: Turns out it was an error in the GET url, last place I thought to look!

Answer (score 0):

Propably your server need Authentication with usage of base64 encoding.  You can test your request in browser. Try  **Postman.**